# In how many ways can a test paper of six questions be attempted, each question being of a TRUE/FALSE type?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can a test paper of six questions be attempted, each question being of a TRUE/FALSE type?

- $0$ questions attempted out of $6$ then $0*0!=0$
- $1$ Question attempted out of $6$ then $1*2!=2$
- $2$ Questions attempted out of $6$ then $2*2!*2!=8$
- $3$ Questions attempted out of $6$ then $3*2!*2!*2!=24$
- $4$ Questions attempted out of $6$ then $4*2!*2!*2!*2!=64$
- $5$ Questions attempted out of $6$ then $5*2!*2!*2!*2!*2!=160$
- $6$ Questions attempted out of $6$ then $6*2!*2!*2!*2!*2!*2!=384$

Summing $0+2+8+24+64+160+384=642$.

Even then I'm still way off the accepted answer of $729$ How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you only attempt one question, there are $12$ ways because you choose which question (out of 6) and then how to answer it.  Try applying this logic to the other list items.

Comment: There's an implicit assumption missing here: you can bubble each question as true, false, or blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every question has three methods to be handled: TRUE, FALSE or unattempted. Hence your answer is $3^6=729$. In some of your cases like case 2, you have left put the permutations on the question which is attempted. It should be for case 2: $6 \times 2= 12$

Answer (score 1):

For each of the six questions, there are three options: true, false, or omit.  Hence, there are $3^6$ ways to attempt a true/false test with six questions.

The reason your answer is too small is that you did not account for the number of ways of selecting which questions would be attempted.  There are $\binom{6}{k}$ ways to select exactly $k$ of the $6$ questions to be attempted and $2$ ways to answer each of the selected questions.  Hence, the number of ways to attempt exactly $k$ of the six questions is
$$\binom{6}{k}2^k$$
Since the number of questions which can be attempted can vary from $0$ to $6$, the number of ways to attempt the test paper is
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}2^k$$
Why are our two answers equivalent?

By the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),
$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}1^{n - k}x^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
Substituting $6$ for $n$ and $2$ for $x$ yields
$$3^n = (1 + 2)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^6 \binom{6}{k}2^k$$